# Is there a simple way to create page transitions between sharepoint pages?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

The wanted an effect that when a page is forwarded to the next page after 15 seconds a page transition like  float left, right , slide would happen to the next sharepoint page?

Could this be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you sarcasm? Hope you have a better day,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could insert a CEWP with javascript redirecting the page after 15 seconds, and triggering a transition like fade (http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3tutorials/a/fade-in-and-out-with-css3.htm) just before.

Comment: Hello andersbs, I found this in a lot of places but I have never seen it utilized on SharePoint. With some tweaking perhaps. but I haven't had much luck figuring it out.
http://git.blivesta.com/animsition/